# How to do projections on a matrix space equipped with an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> In the inner product space $M_{2\times2}$ with $A\cdot B =
> \operatorname{trace}(A^\top B)$, find the projection from $A$ to $B$:
>   $$
> A=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 3&4},\ B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}.
> $$

Do you just solve it as a regular projection? 
$$
\operatorname{proj}_B(A) = \frac{A\cdot B}{\|B\|^2} B.
$$
Would you just get the matrix $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You may read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to learn how to type mathematics with MathJax.

Comment: Hint: $B$ is a unit basis vector.